# ASP.NET MVC 4 List<T> to ICollection<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

My project involves adding a collection of artists to an event.  Currently I have the list of artists from a checkbox form in the view and then i have a List populated with the artists selected from the form.  I am at a sticking point as I need to get that list into the Event (see the //code needed here comment).  I will be performing a similar operation on the Journal class after this.

**Model**

```
public class EventArtistModel
{
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public string ArtistName { get; set; }
    public string ArtistGenre { get; set; }
}

public class Event
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Event Name")]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Location")]
    public string location { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Event Date")]
    public string date { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Artist> Artists { get; set; }
}

public class Artist
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Journal> Journals { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult AddArtistToEvent(int id = 0)
    {
        Event even = db.Events.Find(id);
        List<Artist> artists = even.Artists.Cast<Artist>().ToList();

        var model = db.Artists
            .OrderBy(a => a.Name)
            .Select(a => new EventArtistModel
            {
                EventId = id,
                ArtistName = a.Name,
                ArtistGenre = a.Genre
            });
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult AddToEvent(Artist[] artistsSelected, int id = 0)
    {
        List<Artist> artistList = new List<Artist>();
        foreach (Artist artist in artistsSelected)
        {
            artistList.Add(artist);
        }

        //code needed here

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<EventJournal3.Models.EventArtistModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add an Artist To an Event";
}

@section featured {
    <section class="featured">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <hgroup class="title">
                <h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>
            </hgroup>
        </div>
    </section>
}

@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    var id = item.EventId;
    ViewBag.Message = id.ToString();
}
<form action="/Artist/AddToEvent/@ViewBag.Message" method="post">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <ul>
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        var id = item.EventId;
                        <li>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ArtistName)
                            ~~ <input type="checkbox" name="selectedArtists" value="@item.ArtistName"/>
                        </li>
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                @if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
                {
                    <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-info" />
                }
                | @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Your checkboxes are named `selectedArtists` but your method parameter is `artistsSelected` it wont bind, and in case it would need to be `string[] selectedArtists`. And what on earth is `form action="/Artist/AddToEvent/@ViewBag.Message"`? Use strongly typed html helpers to render your html - no wonder your having problems. And the parameter `int id` will always be zero. Forget this a use view models to represent what you want to display and edit (including a `bool IsSelected` property for `Artist`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult AddToEvent(Artist[] artistsSelected, int id = 0)
{
    Event _event = db.Events.Find(id);
    foreach (Artist artist in artistsSelected)
    {
        _event.Artists.Add(artist);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Be careful, `event` is a reserved keyword in C#